# Can azure active directory manage user outside organization?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to create project management app, and control authorization to related copmanies.

I read that Identity provider is used to control authorization, so I guess that using Azure AD, project management app don't have to have their own user database.

Is it possible to control authorization of project management app using Azure AD account's property, for example, organization A and B registered in Azure AD can access some page, but organization C cannot access some page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage users outside the organization(from other companies) just make him a [guest user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal).

You can restrict the users not to access the application by [following this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users)

Comment: Thank you.  I want to give outside users partial access to application, and give full access to organization account. So, I want to set role information to azure ad accounts. Can I do this?

Comment: Why can't you try to restrict user based on the roles(RBAC)? Assigning roles based on tenants.

Comment: My understanding is that, roles(RBAC) are not for restricting access to application resource, but for restricting access to azure resource. Can application use role information to control access ? and sorry, I am trying understand tenants yet.

Comment: I am talking about RBAC implementation with your application level. Using RBAC with [Application Roles and Role Claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps), developers can securely enforce authorization in their apps with little effort on their part.